# Firebase returning Unknown data from child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from firebase table but it is giving me a user which is not  present in firebase database.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")

    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapShot: DataSnapshot!) in

        let totalUsers = snapShot.childrenCount
        self.usersRefHandle = ref.observe(.childAdded , with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

            print(snapshot.key)
```

it is printing all keys in alphabetical order but suddenly i am getting a key which is not present in my users table.Help me here please.
Thank You!

Comment: Something can be said if you attach your database structure for this.

Comment: You appear to be adding  a .value observer to ref, which reads in all child nodes within ref and fires an event for any changes within the node. Then you're also adding a .childAdded event to the ref node as well. So you read in everything with .value, and then read it all in again with .childAdded. Is that what you meant to do? If it is, can you explain the use case? Also, by doing that, when a child is added not only will an event fire for the child that was added, it will also fire again (.value) and then re-read all the data within the users node. Also, Firebase has no tables, it's NoSQL.

Comment: You're also continually overwriting your ref and snapshot vars because the var names are being re-used within the closure(s).